# Python MatPlotLib Issue: Error in Visualisation of a Polar Contour Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour, visual-glitch

I am writing a program using Python and MatPlotLib and have encountered an issue with creating a contour polar plot.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    from math import sin, cos, radians, sqrt, pi
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

    pandaData = {'alpha':  allAlphas, 'beta': allBetas, 'z': allMinSigmaThetas}
    pandaDF = pd.DataFrame(pandaData)

    theta = np.radians(pandaDF.beta)
    rad = pandaDF.alpha

    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_size_inches(5.5, 5.5)
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.tricontourf(rad * np.cos(theta), rad * np.sin(theta), pandaDF.z, levels=256, cmap='jet')
    plt.axis('off')
    ax = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position(), polar=True)
    ax.set_facecolor('none')
    ax.set_ylim(0, rad.max())
    ax.set_rticks([0, 30, 60, 90])
    ax.grid(alpha=0.5)
    # fig.colorbar(c, ax=ax, pad=0.1)
    plt.show()
```

I have created similar code using a scatter plot to create something which looks like this:
[Scatter Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y29nJ.png)

I am looking to create a gradient visualisation which has a colour bar on the side. The code above is what I used to produce this image, which I am happy with: [Contour Plot without Colour Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnGuQ.png)

However, when I uncomment the second-last line of the code to add the colour bar, or when I change one of the values in the fig.set_size_inches() function, the whole plot goes haywire:  [Contour Plot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZTld.png)

With the scatter plot, doing either of these things causes the whole plot to scale accordingly without overlap. But with the contour plot, this isn't working.

I have tried padding the colour bar, but that doesn't work. Essentially the colour gradient scales independently of the axis and the colour bar, causing weird overlapping.

I would like the contour plot to have a colour bar, and the ability to be scaled up without distorting like this. Any advise would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Mar